# SyntaxError (Python Jupyter Notebook)

Tags: python

Not sure How to fix this.

> SyntaxError: Missing parentheses in call to 'print'. Did you mean print(IM.dtype # prints image type)?

```
plt.figure(figsize=(60,30))

IM = mh.imread('TestNodose.png')  # Loads in image
print IM.dtype                    # prints image type
pylab.imshow(IM)                  # shows image
pylab.gray()                      # makes it greyscale
pylab.show()
```

[image]

Comment: > Did you mean print(IM.dtype # prints image type)?

whenever you have a hunch like this, you should go on and try. No harm if the test is failed but in this case you could have gotten the answer by yourself, which is more rewarding! :)

Answer (score 1):

This is basically syntax error.
Your notebook is using Python 3, and in Python 3 `print` function require parenthesis. Correct syntax: `print()`

In python 2, we don't need the parenthesis.

Answer (score 0):

in python 2 `print` don't need parenthesis, however you have to write them in python3.
The correct syntax is

```py
print(IM.DTYPE)
```

because your jupyter notebook is using python 3